# rendering JSON data to HTML table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have XML data which is needed to be render in HTML as Table, for convenience i have converted it to JSON for data extraction.

Find demo [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/bsmj5jpm/)

required table - [image: OUTPUT]

My code is working fine. But it is breaking some where after cell `CC` due to error `_relIndex` is undefined (as shown on console).

But i think its breaking because of `json.Table.Row[i].Cell.length` in FOR loop is showing `undefined` for the first Blank spacer in table after cell `CC`

help.

Comment: You are calling cell.length which does mean a cell has no length try fix cell.length to row.length or something

Comment: @DagmFekadu Yes `cell.length` essentially gives me number of cell as they are not fix for any row

Comment: Means every cell has two dimentions?

Comment: @DagmFekadu Nope. but cell has property associated with it